# Determine Current Page

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I have an AppBar with a button that launches a popup that contains a list that the user selects and upon one being selected it refreshes the page, but before it refreshes for a certain page I need it to execute a task. The code works great on my other pages. I just need it to execute

```
await home.DatabaseTest();
```

before it refreshes the page and I only want it to execute if the current page is Dashboard

```
private async void customerNamePopUp_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets the selected Customer Name and stores it in the Database.
        barCustomerName = db.selectCustomerNumberByCustomerName(customerNamePopUp.SelectedItem);
        rh.appDataHandler(customerNamePopUp.SelectedIndex, barCustomerName);
        if ("WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO TEST IF PAGE EQUALS DASHBOARD")
        {
            await home.DatabaseTest();
        }

        if (this.Frame != null)
        {
            //Refreshes Current Page
            Frame1.Navigate(Frame1.Content.GetType(), RootPage);                
        }
    }
```

See note in loop before the await task to know what I am asking for.

Thank you

Comment: Visual Studio is an editor and is not relevant to the current code; just the user creating the code. A better tag would be the .Net version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
if (Frame1.Content.GetType() == typeof(Dashboard))
        {
            await home.DatabaseTest();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a public enum where each item correlates to each page.
2. On the App page create a static property of the enum created which will signify the current page.
3. On each page's OnNavigatedTo method set the app static property to that page's enum.
4. Wherever needed check that variable for the current page.